# Find p for the series to be convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^2\log n)\cdot(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)^p} $$

For which real values of p is the series convergent?

I really have no idea about this question, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have anything of your own to add, Cindy? This is nothing more, nothing less than a problem statement, with absolutely no comments from you, attempts you've made, any expressed motivation for why you are asking, no source given, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac {\ln (n)}{n}=0 \implies $$

$$(n^\frac 1n-1)^p=(e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln (n)}-1)^p $$
$$\sim (\frac {\ln (n)}{n})^p $$

thus the general term is equivalent to

$$u_n=\frac {1}{n^{2-p}(\ln (n))^{p+1}} $$

It is a Bertrand series.

If $2-p>1$ , it converges since
$$\lim_{+\infty}n^\alpha u_n=0$$ where $$2-p>\alpha>1$$

If $2-p<1$, it diverges since
$$\lim_{+\infty}n^\beta u_n=+\infty $$
where $$2-p <\beta <1$$

If $2-p=1$, it converges by comparison 
with the integral.

> Finally, it converges $\iff p \le 1$.

Comment: You also may refer to the known results on *Bertrand's series*, to make it shorter.

Comment: It is in seventh line of the answer. thnx.